# How to use Settings.Global, Settings.Secure and Settings.System in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to use above mentioned classes and want to retrieve information from their static Constants. I want to retrieve information like this. For example from `Settings.Secure`

```
SETTINGS_SECURE
ADB_ENABLED=1
ALLOWED_GEOLOCATION_ORIGINS=http://www.google.co.uk 
ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION=0
ANDROID_ID=200142d4dfd4e641
```

But I am actually getting this Output:

```
SETTINGS_SECURE
ADB_ENABLED=adb_enabled
ALLOWED_GEOLOCATION_ORIGINS=allowed_geolocation_origins
ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION=allow_mock_location
ANDROID_ID=android_id
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just retrieving the constants' values. As a quick example that will illustrate the difference, to produce the above output:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SETTINGS_SECURE\n");

sb.append(Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED.toUpperCase())
    .append("=")
    .append(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED))
    .append("\n")

    .append(Settings.Secure.ALLOWED_GEOLOCATION_ORIGINS.toUpperCase())
    .append("=")
    .append(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ALLOWED_GEOLOCATION_ORIGINS))
    .append("\n")

    .append(Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION.toUpperCase())
    .append("=")
    .append(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION))
    .append("\n")

    .append(Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID.toUpperCase())
    .append("=")
    .append(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
```